# Add auto complete list/table over a `UITableView` when user tap on a cell with `UITextField`

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cgrect

I have implemented an autocomplete table, that shows up when the user selects the Model field in my table.

However, I am having issues controlling how it appears. I would ultimately like the Models Cell to scroll up to the top, the autocomplete table to show between it and the keyboard. Nothing I try will cause this table to act in that nature.

In this example the autocomplete table is showing up under the header titles when the user starts to type 'F'

[image]

The Autocomplete table is initialized and then hidden. Only when the Model textfield begins editing does it show up.

Here is the code the creates the table.

```
 CGRect frameAuto = CGRectMake(0, self.txt_model.frame.origin.y + self.txt_model.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.txt_model.frame.size.height * 3);

    self.autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frameAuto style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
    self.autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.autocompleteTableView];
```

I guess what I am needing help with, is ***how do I get the Model textfield to move up to the Navigation bar, show the autocomplete table and leave room for the keyboard?***

**UPDATE** --
Adding the autocompletetableview as an accessory view does this:

Creating the autocomplete table

```
self.autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
    self.autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.autocompleteTableView];
```

Setting the textfield

```
    self.txt_model.delegate = self;
    self.txt_model.inputView = self.autocompleteTableView;
   self.txt_model.inputAccessoryView = self.autocompleteTableView;
```

Textfield delegate

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender {
    if(sender == self.txt_model){
        NSLog(@"Moving view up");
       [self.tblDetailsView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

    }
```

Presents the entire autocompletetable over the the input form.

Keyboard is not present nor the textfield.

[image]

Comment: What I suggest you do is use your tableview but put it in a `UIView animation` block. Have it hidden under the view and then when you begin editing move the view up above the keyboard with another textfield containing the contents of what you've already typed in that textfield(another textfield). Use some logic (if the textifield is empty or you end editing, close the tableview). There's a lot to do here for sure. You're going to have possibly set up some `UITextFieldDelegate` methods as well

Comment: There is a alignment issue with your second image. Could you fixe it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the effect you are looking for you could try setting it as the inputAccessoryView on the UITextField you are editing. This will stick it directly to the top of the keyboard. I'm not sure how well a UITableView will work as the inputAccessoryView but it might be worth a try.

self.textView.inputAccessoryView = autocompleteTableView

Comment: If it covers the keyboard... how will the user type to drill down the autocomplete area?

Comment: It won't cover the keyboard, it will sit right above it between the keyboard and your other table.

Comment: For example, this is how Apple does the message box that sits on above the keyboard on the iMessage app.

Comment: Here is a decent writeup about this: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/

Comment: You should not do this line: self.txt_model.inputView = self.autocompleteTableView; Setting the inputView replaces the keyboard. You only wan to set the inputAccessoryView to your tableView.

Comment: So I removed that line, and the keyboard still does not show.

Comment: I created an example for you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtuh7ljoosasn9c/InputAccessoryExample.zip?dl=1

Comment: I just realized I made this in Swift 1.2 so you will need Xcode 6.3 Beta to run it but it should still give you the idea.

Comment: hmmm i couldn't get it to run

Comment: However, I do have the text field inputAccessoryView set to the autoCompleteTableView. It just doesn't perform as you describe. Perhaps make your code in Objective-C?

Comment: Here it is in ObjC. https://www.dropbox.com/s/tz8uua0qf9d1j47/InputAccessoryExample2.zip?dl=0

Comment: The only thing I can see that is diffenrent is this line [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

Comment: is registerClass important to your implementation?

Comment: In your example, the tableview shows up, but there is no keyboard

Comment: I got it work. Thanks so much for your help! That was way simpler than trying to make a new view and push it on the stack and move everything around

Answer (score 0):

I don't think creating an `UITableView` and add it on top of the existing `UITableView` is a very good idea. I suggest the following two options for what you want to achieve.

**Option 1 Modify the existing `UITableView`**:

You can defined two modes for your table view. And normal mode, and a edit mode.

In normal mode, you display the table view as it is. When a user tap a text field, we will enter edit mode.

In edit mode, you do the following,

- Show the the row that the user tap on as the very first row (row 0).
- Show the auto complete options bellow (row 1, 2, 3, ...).

Use will enter the exit the edit mode either by tapping on one of the autocomplete options row or by hitting enter key in the keyboard to indicate finish typing and back to normal mode.

**Option 2 Navigate to a new view**:

You can navigate to a new table view with the autocomplete options. When user is done editing (either finished typing or select on one of the rows, move back to the previous view and update the table view. I personally prefer the this second approach. But both approach will require a certain amount of work.

Comment: i tried the scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: but it would never actually scroll to the cell.

Comment: @Firemarble, the reason why the table view is not scrolling is probably because that you don't have enough table view cells in the table view to allow for the scrolling. For example, if you have only 5 rows and they all fit well in the current screen, you will never be able to scroll the bottom row to the top.

Comment: The autotable scrolls fine. Everything that deals with population and manipulation of the data/table is fine with the exception of presentation.

Comment: @Firemarble, I have make a modification to option one. Instead of trying to scroll the table view to the right position, maybe the following is more robust? How about replace the whole data source for the table view when a user tap on a textfield. So we show only the row that the user tap on as the first row and the options below. Please take a look at my edits in the answer and let me know how you think about this.

Comment: @Firemarble, the benefits of replacing the table view data source instead of trying scroll to the right position is that you don't need to worry about those weird side effects when a user manually scroll the table view.